# Reference request: Leaf-heavy master theorem algorithms

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, recursion, master-theorem

I know many algorithms that can be analyzed using master theorem, but the only algorithm I know where the time is dominated by the leaves is fast matrix multiplication.

Are there other recursive algorithms (not necessarily master-theorem-style -- can be akra bazzi/something similar) where the time is dominated by the leaves? Would be grateful for any references.